# How to pass array value from one function to another function in php?

Tags: php, function

I am selecting multiple Id from Page1 and sending to Page2 which is working, Now I have to display all id to function name `fake_user_archive` for delete. I am getting empty value in the function.

Example:
I have id no 1,5,20,50. I selected from Page1 and sending that id to page2. My code will check the email status if the status is 1 it will call the next function which is called as `fake_user_archive` and there email will delete. but I am not getting any value inside the function.
**page1.php**

This is not my whole code. only for reference.

```
<?php
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo"<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='".$id."'>";
}?>
```

**Page2.php**

```
    switch($_GET['function']) {
    case 'checking':checking($conn);break;
    default : redirect('index.php');
    }
    function checking($conn)
    {
    // loop over checked checkboxes
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $checkbox) {

        //echo $checkbox;//displaying all id
        $sql_all="SELECT * FROM `request` WHERE Id='".$checkbox."'";
        $result_chk=$conn->query($sql_all);
           if (isset($result_chk->num_rows) > 0) {
               while($row = $result_chk->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $r_email_verify=$row['email_verification'];

               }
           }

           if ($r_email_verify == 1) {
              fake_user_archive($conn);//calling the function but getting empty
           }
else{
other_function();
}

    }//foreach

    }

    function fake_user_archive($conn)
    {
        // how do i get here all my id which is selected from page1.php
        //deactive id here
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass $conn to the function, which seems to be your database connection? You said you wanted to pass an id - so what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Pass `$checkbox` instead of `$conn`. `fake_user_archive($checkbox);`

Comment: pass it as second parameter like this fake_user_archive($conn,$checkbox);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** you can pass `N` number of `parameter` to function pass it like this

```
fake_user_archive($conn,$checkbox);
```

**2nd :** function should be

```
function fake_user_archive($conn,$checkbox)
{
   var_dump($checkbox);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it is not working, inside function I tried to display echo $checkbox but nothing is displayed

Comment: inside the function you can put var_dump($checkbox); exit; and see the output @NarendraVerma

Comment: What I did I selected id number 4858,4859,4860 and i got output like array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "4858" [1]=> string(4) "4859" [2]=> string(4) "4860" } array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "4858" [1]=> string(4) "4859" [2]=> string(4) "4860" }

Comment: yeah it's passing as a  array . may be you used var_dump() twice so it's eching twice . otherwise  what problem with it @NarendraVerma

Comment: $sql_filled_blank="UPDATE `request` SET archive=1 WHERE Id='".$checkbox."'";

Comment: Above query is used for changing the archive of each id. then How can I use it. should I use foreach?

Comment: no need foreach because inside the function you will get only one id for each iteration function fake_user_archive($conn,$checkbox)
{
   var_dump($checkbox);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147356/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-jyothi).

Comment: Working for me.Thanks for your help jyothi